# Installing Ubuntu TV

Tags: login-screen, ubuntu-tv

I have installed desktop and wanted to install Ubuntu TV. I followed [the instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuTV/Contributing), and rebooted to the login screen. I clicked unity 2D, but it just takes me back to my main login screen, where I have to enter a password again. Loop?

How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicated http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop